# NVIDIA-SMI, NVML, Power usage: [NOT SUPPORTED]

Tags: gpu, nvidia, nvml

I tried to get current power usage with the following command in Windows 10 x64:

> nvidia-smi.exe --format=csv,noheader --query-gpu=power.draw

And got the next result:

> [Not Supported]

I checked it on the GTX1050(notebook) video card.
Please also see the nvidia-smi output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 382.05                 Driver Version: 382.05                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050   WDDM  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   38C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    319MiB /  2048MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Also tried to get this info via
[NVML library:](http://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/nvml-api/index.html)

```
nvmlReturn_t result;
nvmlDevice_t device;
result = nvmlInit();
if (NVML_SUCCESS != result)
{
    printf("Failed to initialize NVML: %s\n", nvmlErrorString(result));
    return 1;
}
result = nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(0, &device);
if (NVML_SUCCESS != result)
{
    printf("Failed to get handle for device %i: %s\n", 0, nvmlErrorString(result));
}
unsigned int power_usage = 0;
result = nvmlDeviceGetPowerUsage(device, &power_usage);
printf(nvmlErrorString(result));
```

The output is the same:

> Not Supported

**First question:** Is exist the way to get the power usage or other parameter from NVIDIA card which is not supported?
Please also see the Feature Matrix part in the old
[manual](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/cuda/files/CUDADownloads/NVML_cuda5/nvml.4.304.55.pdf#Feature%20Matrix)
 it contain the information about features supported NVIDIA cards. 
**Second question:** Is exist such docs about new video cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with `NVIDIA GT1030`. It seems that some features including the feature you mention is no longer supported by NVIDIA in newer drivers. I solved the problem by installing an older version. Try finding the first version of driver that included support for your GPU. Check this [link](http://www.guru3d.com/files-categories/videocards-nvidia-geforce-vista-%7C-7.html).